# I am getting time out error while running query using vb.net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am getting time out error while running query using vb.net, if I run the same query through SQL Server its running with in 0 sec? I am not Getting What's wrong with the code or query or connection

Comment: can you paste which query or command you are running ? also code, what you have tried.

Comment: Hi! Actually the problem was with trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted) this. The table was locked in trans so it was giving error. Than you very much.